# TypeError: user.addTechs is not a function sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js

Tenho uma associação entre tecnologias e usuários. A associação é N:N. Estou tentando acessar os métodos auxiliares gerados pelo Sequelize mas estou obtendo esse erro:

```
TypeError: user.addTechs is not a function
```

Model da tabela que armazena nome de tecnologias:

```
    const { Model, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

class Tech extends Model {
    static init(sequelize){

        super.init({
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
        }, {sequelize, tableName: "techs"})
    };

    static associate(models){
        this.belongsToMany(models.User, {foreignKey: "tech_id", through: "user_techs", as: "users"})
    };
};

module.exports = Tech;
```

Model da tabela users:

```
    const {Model, DataTypes, DatabaseError } = require("sequelize"); 

class User extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            name: DataTypes.STRING, 
            email: DataTypes.STRING,  
        }, {sequelize})
    }
    
    static associate(models){
        this.hasMany(models.Address, {foreignKey:"user_id", as: 'addresses'}); 
        this.belongsToMany(models.Tech, {foreignKey: "user_id", through: "user_techs", as: "techs"});
    }
}

module.exports = User;
```

De onde o erro está vindo (TechController.js):

```
const Tech = require("../models/techModel");
const User = require("../models/userModel");

module.exports = {
    index: async function () { },
    store: async function (req, res) {
        const { user_id } = req.params;
        const { name } = req.body;

        const user = await User.findByPk(user_id);

        if (!user) return res.json({ error: "user not found" });
        const [tech] = await Tech.findOrCreate({ where: { name } });

        await user.addTechs(tech); // O erro parte daqui. 

        res.json(tech);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, mas ainda sigo sem entender o pq de não ter funcionado. Sempre que eu crio uma associação eu tenho que declarar ela em algum lugar. Nesse caso eu estava criando ela em src/database/index. Até aí beleza, eu tinha algo assim:

```
  const Sequelize = require("sequelize");  
const dbConfig = require('../config/database'); 

const Users = require("../models/usersModel"); 
const Address = require("../models/addressModel"); 
const Techs = require("../models/techModel");

const connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig);

Users.init(connection);
Address.init(connection); 
Techs.init(connection); 

Users.associate(connection.models);
Address.associate(connection.models);
Techs.associate(connection.models);

module.exports = connection;
```

Tive uma ideia brilhante (contem ironia leve) pra caso a aplicação crescesse, eu não precisar ficar digitando toda vez:

```
model.init(connection);
model.associate(connection.model)
```

ideia:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const dbConfig = require("../config/database");

const Address = require('../models/addressModel');
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const Tech = require('../models/techModel');

const connection = new Sequelize(dbConfig);
const models = [Address, User, Tech];
const initializations = async () => {
    let modelsCounter = 0;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        models.forEach(model => {
          
            if (modelsCounter === models.length) resolve();
            model.init(connection);
            modelsCounter += 1;
       
        });
    });
}


const associations = async () => {
    let modelsCounter = 0;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        models.forEach(model => {
            if(modelsCounter ===  models.length) resolve();
            model.associate(connection.models);
            modelsCounter+=1; 
        });
    } )
};

const database = async ()=> {
    await initializations(); 
    await associations();
}

database();
module.exports = connection;
```

Desse modo eu apenas precisaria adicionar um novo model ao array "models". Mas não funciona. Agora eu quero saber o por quê...

Answer (score -2):

tudo bem?

Seu método addTechs não foi declarado nem na classe User nem na Tech, por isso não é possível invocá-lo.

Comment: Esse método addTechs é um método criado pelo Sequelize sempre que crio uma associação. E nesse exemplo associei Users com Techs, que nesse caso é uma associação N:N.  Por padrão o Sequelize acaba criando esses métodos conforme descrito aqui https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#special-methodsmixins-added-to-instances. 
Só que por algum motivo, isso não funciona. 

Aqui a doc mostra mais detalhadamente pra associações N:N: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#foobelongstomanybar--through-baz-